# What components do I need to build a Metro-style app in WPF?

Tags: wpf, microsoft-metro

I have to create an application in WPF that has to be very fancy. I would like to create it with a Metro-like style like WP7 apps.

Do you know if there are components that can be used to obtain a similar style?

Comment: Check out [MetroTwit](http://metrotwit.com).

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592326/making-wpf-applications-look-metro-styled-even-in-windows-7-window-chrome-t

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Elysium](http://elysiumproject.net/), which licensed under MIT license and included ApplicationBar and ToastNotification classes.

Comment: Elysium installation guide and sample code - http://bizvise.com/2012/09/27/how-to-create-metro-style-window-on-wpf-using-elysium/

Answer (score 6):

What I think is a good solution, is to take the original Metro Styles of the Windows Phone 7 and ajust them that they fit Windows requirements.

A good one to start with is the LightBlue Style which can be found here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Design

And I found an other promissing framework on codeplex. http://metrotoolkit.codeplex.com/  (But I did not check it out until now.)

Comment: Just a heads up Metro Toolkit contained copyrighted XAML code reversed engineered from MetroTwit (my project) and redistributed without permission.

Comment: @Long, the OP has asked a further question about your product: [WPF interface like MetroTwit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417717/wpf-interface-like-metrotwit), obviously you are the best placed person to answer it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MahApps.metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/). It's very cool.

Comment: Indeed MahApps is promising. But the only drawback is they don't include some vital controls like DataGrid and DateTimePicker, which you need in almost every LOB application. DataGrid and D.P. has long become a part of WPF.

Comment: You can ask this things from MahApps developers, they will response and make them ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I use [Modern UI for WPF](https://mui.codeplex.com/) to style my WPF applications. It supports MVVM and looks really great.