# Metro vs WPF for Windows 8 development?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to get my head around the future of development for Windows 8. My understanding is that developing Metro apps will mean they are strictly Windows 8 only.

But there are technologies out there, see [How to build a Metro App in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391888/how-to-build-a-metro-app-in-wpf), which means WPF could be used to make something have that Metro look and feel.

So am I right in understanding that a WPF app could be developed - and run on Windows 7 - but also run on Windows 8? If only Metro apps can be run from the new Start screen in Windows 8, does that mean traditional style apps can still be run through the desktop mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Normal” Windows applications can still run fine in Desktop mode. In fact, if you have such an application it will likely just run the same as it does on Windows 7 and you don't really need to feel pressured to create a Windows Store app (formerly known as Metro).

The question you linked to talks about something entirely else, though. It's for creating applications like Zune or the Github Windows client in WPF. They have a certain aesthetic that is Metro-like but they're not actually Windows Store apps. You cannot use WPF for creating the latter, although most key concepts are similar or identical.

Answer (score 0):

Metro is just the design language.

A traditional WPF can run on Windows 7 and on the Windows 8 desktop. These can't be run on Windows RT devices.

Modern apps, i.e. Windows 8/RT apps or Windows Store apps can't be written with WPF and only run on Windows 8 and Windows RT.

Answer (score 0):

Metro is much more than a GUI. It is able to access the [Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) providing common functionality like webcam access.

However using WPF you can 'mock' the metro visual layer. But they will be traditional desktop applications that will run under desktop mode in windows 8.

I would suggest to develop 2 GUI layers (metro and desktop).